# How to install numpy on vscode on mac?

Tags: numpy, pip

It's saying:

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'"
```

and then when I do "pip install numpy" it says:

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (1.16.6)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are using python 3.X while pip is configured for python 2.X.

Try running `pip3 install numpy`

Basically you are installing a package for python 2, while running the script with python 3.

Comment: I have tried this. It still is giving me the same output

Comment: Do you mind sharing the code you are running and how you are running it?